# How to search for an integer in a list on Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, list, pygame

the function, 'Search for integer' (or searchArray in the coding) is supposed to let the user enter a value, e.g 4, and if 4 is in the list, then it will return a message saying, "Yes, 4 is in this list." I'm pretty sure I've got the coding right... but the message wont show

```
def searchArray(array):
    message = ""
    length = len(array)
    numStr = getUserText("Enter a positive integer to search for")
    num = checkInt(numStr, "Sorry that's not an integer, try again")
    try:
        array.index(numStr)
        message = "The number " + str(index) + " was found in the array."
    except ValueError:
        message = str(numStr) + " was not found." + " "

    return message
```

^ when i print the message, nothing shows up, it is blank.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
The key here is "minimal" -- most of your code merely distracts from your problem.  Write a short main program to call your function and show the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: You have an array of int, but you're searching for `numStr`, not `num`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array contains integers, but you're searching for `numStr`, which contains a string. You should search for `num`.

Also, there's no variable `index`, you meant `numStr`.

```
    try:
        array.index(num)
        message = "The number " + numStr + " was found in the array."
    except ValueError:
        message = numStr + " was not found." + " "
```

Answer (score 0):

The `in` keyword lets you check membership. Works on lists, sets, dicts, etc.

```
def searchArray(array):
    length = len(array)
    numStr = getUserText("Enter a positive integer to search for")
    num = checkInt(numStr, "Sorry that's not an integer, try again")
    if num in array:
        return f"The number {num} was found, at index {array.index(num)}."
    else:
        return f"The number {num} was not found."
```

Comment: Why does this work differently than using `array.index` and catching the error?

Comment: You also changed which variable you're searching for, that's the real problem.